# ARM Toolchain build error with linaro ABE on ubuntu

Tags: arm, toolchain, gnu-toolchain

Good morning,

I have been trying for months to build a gcc toolchain for arm. it is maining for test purposes in my research. I wanted to add fortran to campabilities to it for both the rmprofile and aprofile. I know arm has one for the aprofile but not for the rmprofile.

I have tried everything I know. At the moment I decided to use Linaro ABE and i keep getting and error in  gcc stage1. specifically when it start configuring libstdc++-v3. I've gone through the config.log and don't even know where to start correcting this. I am not conversant with which libraries to adjust. I would really appreciate any help.I will also appreciate any links that will help in understanding this better. I have pasted part of the config and makefile logs.

```
$ /home/oad/abebuild/snapshots/gcc/libstdc++-v3/configure --srcdir=/home/oad/abebuild/snapshots
/gcc/libstdc++-v3 --cache-file=./config.cache
--with-cross-host=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --enable-lto --enable-shared --without-included-gettext --enable-nls --with-system-zlib --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --disable-libstdcxx-pch --enable-c99 --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-long-long --with-cloog=no --with-ppl=no --enable-multilib --with-multilib-list=rmprofile,aprofile --enable-threads=no --disable-multiarch --disable-libssp --disable-libquadmath --disable-threads --without-headers --with-newlib --disable-libmudflap --disable-bootstrap --disable-decimal-float --disable-libgomp --disable-libatomic --disable-libsanitizer --disable-plugins --disable-libitm --with-sysroot=/home/oad/abebuild/builds/sysroot-arm-eabi --disable-shared --with-glibc-version=2.18 --prefix=/home/oad/abebuild/builds/destdir/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu --enable-languages=c,c++,lto --program-transform-name=s&^&arm-none-eabi-& --disable-option-checking --with-target-subdir=arm-none-eabi --build=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu --host=arm-none-eabi --target=arm-none-eabI

uname -s = Linux uname -v = #168~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Sat Jan 19
11:26:28 UTC 2019

---------

checking stdbool.h usability... no checking stdbool.h presence... yes
configure: WARNING: stdbool.h: present but cannot be compiled
configure: WARNING: stdbool.h:     check for missing prerequisite
headers? configure: WARNING: stdbool.h: see the Autoconf documentation
configure: WARNING: stdbool.h:     section "Present But Cannot Be
Compiled" configure: WARNING: stdbool.h: proceeding with the
compiler's result checking for stdbool.h... no checking stdalign.h
usability... no checking stdalign.h presence... yes configure:
WARNING: stdalign.h: present but cannot be compiled configure:
WARNING: stdalign.h:     check for missing prerequisite headers?
configure: WARNING: stdalign.h: see the Autoconf documentation
configure: WARNING: stdalign.h:     section "Present But Cannot Be
Compiled" configure: WARNING: stdalign.h: proceeding with the
compiler's result checking for stdalign.h... no checking for the value
of EOF... configure: error: computing EOF failed make[1]: ***
[configure-target-libstdc++-v3] Error 1 make[1]: Leaving directory
`/home/oad/abebuild/builds/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/arm-none-eabi/gcc-stage1'
make: *** [all] Error 2 make: Leaving directory
`/home/oad/abebuild/builds/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/arm-none-eabi/gcc-stage1'
```